# Why are my non-python files not being packaged?

Tags: python, packaging, pypi

I'm new to packaging in Python. I've tried to specify my non-python files within setup.py's 'scripts' argument, and also specifying the file within MANIFEST.in, however after I package the file using `python setup.py build sdist` and install using pip, only the files with the `.py` extension make it to the `site-packages/my_package` directory.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

15 minutes later I find the answer. `sdist` only includes the `*.py` files. I just changed the command to use `bdist_wheel` and all the files I needed were included.